# Taylor expansion of the series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

function f is given by an equation:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{3+x^3}$$ Find the taylor expansion in a point $x_0=0$ and calculate radiu of the convergence.
Could you explain how to find taylor expansion of such series? and thus how to find the radius of convrgence?

Comment: For the radius of convergence, you do not need the Taylor series here. Just search for the closest pole in the complex plane.

Comment: but i want taylor as well

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Use the (famous) expansion
$$ \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}x^n $$
To do this, factor by 3 and consider $x' = -(x^3)/3$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that

$\frac{1}{1-y} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} y^n$ for $|y| < 1$

Rewrite your function as $f(x) = \frac{1}{3(1-\frac{-x^3}{3})}$.

Finally, $y = -x^3/3$